# Keep cabal new-run alive

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, cabal-new

I'm running a `haskell`-based build using `cabal` the following way in dev mode on `ubuntu 20.04`:

```
cabal new-run -- exe:live-docs \
  --database-url='postgres://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>' \
  serve --enable-admin --admin-assets-dir=../admin/static
```

What is the best practice to keep the cabal session working in the background (keep-alive) for production use?

I have looked into the Cabal documentation in vain.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with `cabal`? It is your program, `live-docs`, that decides when to exit, not `cabal`.

Comment: When executing `cabal new-run` the app keeps running until I close the terminal. I'm new to haskell. With `node.js` I use `PM2`.

Comment: That is a statement about your shell, not `cabal` (and not your terminal). Look into `nohup`, double forking, or your shell's documentation about job control... or just don't have its launch be controlled by a shell in a terminal, but rather by systemd or whatever init system you are into.

Comment: `nohup` might help to keep the `cabal new-run` shell script alive. However, the `cabal` commands throw console logs. For production use it is not a good practice as far as I know. I was hoping to see a command option such as `cabal new-run --no-logs --keep-alive` at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to avoid `cabal`'s output (as described in your comments), you have two quick options:

1. Use `-v0` to ask it not to output anything. It will still produce output if building your program fails.

   ```sh
   cabal run -v0 live-docs -- --db etc
   ```
2. Use `cabal` to build, and optionally copy it somewhere central, then just... run your program. This is what most people do. To build and run:

   ```sh
   cabal build live-docs # this produces output and is done once

   # the next three are essentially equivalent options. you do one of them each
   # time you want to start your program
   `cabal list-bin live-docs` --db etc # OR
   cabal exec live-docs -- --db etc # OR
   ./dist-newstyle/<poke around a bit>/live-docs --db etc
   ```

   To build and copy somewhere central:

   ```sh
   cabal install exe:live-docs # done once, produces output

   live-docs --db etc # each time you want to start your program
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. `cabal run -v0 ...` is what I was mainly looking for as I still want to keep using cabal while developing in cloud.